# Fetching bundle in maven central programmatically

Tags: java, spring-boot, bundle, maven-central

I'm looking for a Java API which can be used to search for bundles in from a remote repository. I've found Eclipse Ather so far but it looks over complicated for my needs so i'm seeking for something more simple.

**What I need is:**

I have to specify the location of the remote Maven repository (Maven Central)

I like to fetch/serach an artifact (bundle) based on name + version

Return the location of the artifact, a HTTP URL is preferred (i'll fetch it on my own with eg. Apache HTTP Client)

Comment: Apache Aether..

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: @Nikolas I found Aether, but u need to specify <groupId>:<artifactId>[:<extension>[:<classifier>]]:<version> but i want just made a search based on the name of the jar !